# run javascript on change of <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run javascript on change of a , but not even a simple alert is working. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#spellingSuggestions').on('change', function(){
    alert("hello");
});
```

Here is the code in a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AsqSb/

Comment: include jquery `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/AsqSb/1/

Comment: You didn't select `jQuery` from the sidebar.

Comment: It doesn't work for the same reason `idontexist()` doesn't work in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just enable jQuery.
Or without jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/AsqSb/5/

```
document.getElementById('spellingSuggestions').onchange = function(){
    alert("hello");
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not including jQuery in your fiddle, just make sure to add it and it'll work... (it's on the left side of the window, under `Frameworks & Extensions`):

[image]

If you check the JS console, you'll realize that's the problem because of this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/jSUXT/)

Answer (score 1):

in fiddle you have to select jquery from libs menu